# How to open launcher app automatically after update?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I know How to open App after the update with

**android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED**.

And in Receiver

```
Intent LaunchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("my.package.name");
        mContext.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Above code working perfectly.

But my application is **launcher** application.

A user has to click on **Always** button.

[image]

> **Is there any way to launch my application without click on Always
>   Button.?**

Comment: To make sure I understand, you have an app already installed, and you are adding Launcher capabilities to it?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed app and app have launcher capabilities

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No."

---

Your device already has a Launcher app installed. So now you have 2 apps that both available to receive the intent when the user presses the HOME button. That is why the chooser window is displayed.

Since we cannot change what intent is broadcast when the HOME button is pressed, the only way to not have that popup is if you uninstall the default launcher from your device. And this cannot be done by your app, unless you have system permissions to uninstall the other launcher.

Comment: I think this is possible someway. Because I have seen 2 to 3 kiosk apps that are working like that. If an update comes for that app, they will launch their app as a launcher app.

Comment: I would like to know how. It has been some years since I worked with my Launcher app, so the info might be old. Hopefully someone with more experience can update. I might have to delete this answer.

Comment: I just recently checked, one app is installed on my mobile. My automatically update is on in Playstore, so when I wake up, that app opened as a launcher app.

Comment: Even though it was never previously the default launcher? i.e. You never told it to "always" open that app? @ChiragSavsani

Comment: No, First time I have to open an app, but if I closed my app and also reset launcher and select Google Now Launcher as a default launcher, then also app will open as a launcher on app update.

Comment: Don't delete this question. Leave it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171471/discussion-between-richard-le-mesurier-and-chirag-savsani).